# Find the area of the region bounded by the graphs of $y = x$, $y = 4 − 3x$, and $x = 0$.

Tags: calculus, integration, area

Please help. I got **0.785** but I'm not sure if that is the right answer.

Comment: The region whose area you want to find is a triangle. It shouldn't be too hard to figure out the area of that triangle using elementary methods once you've looked at a diagram. This will allow you to verify your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Make a diagram. You'll get 2 right-angle triangles.

Answer: $0.5 + 1.5 = 2$